# Android ICS 4.0 NDK NewStringUTF is crashing down the App

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-ndk-r7

I have a method in JNI C/C++ which takes jstring and returns back jstring some thing like as below,

```
  NATIVE_CALL(jstring, method)(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jstring filename)
  {

// Get jstring into C string format.
  const char* cs = env->GetStringUTFChars (filename, NULL);
  char *file_path = new char [strlen (cs) + 1]; // +1 for null terminator
  sprintf (file_path, "%s", cs);
  env->ReleaseStringUTFChars (filename, cs);


  reason_code = INTERNAL_FAILURE;
  char* info = start_module(file_path);  


  jstring jinfo ;


  if(info==NULL)
  {
      jinfo = env->NewStringUTF(NULL);
  }
  else
  {
      jinfo = env->NewStringUTF(info);

  }


  delete info;

  info = NULL;
  return jinfo;
  }
```

The code works perfectly with prior android 4.0 versions like 2.2,2.3 and so on. With ICS 4.0 check JNI is on by default and because of it the app crashes throwing the following error

```
 08-25 22:16:35.480: W/dalvikvm(24027): **JNI WARNING: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal  continuation byte 0x40**
08-25 22:16:35.480: W/dalvikvm(24027):              
08-25 22:16:35.480: W/dalvikvm(24027): ==========
08-25 22:16:35.480: W/dalvikvm(24027): /tmp/create
08-25 22:16:35.480: W/dalvikvm(24027): ==========
08-25 22:16:35.480: W/dalvikvm(24027): databytes,indoorgames,drop
08-25 22:16:35.480: W/dalvikvm(24027): ==========���c_ag����ϋ@�ډ@�����@'
 08-25 22:16:35.480: W/dalvikvm(24027):              in Lincom/inter       /ndk/comNDK;.rootNDK:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; **(NewStringUTF)**
08-25 22:16:35.480: I/dalvikvm(24027): "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
08-25 22:16:35.480: I/dalvikvm(24027):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a4b460   self=0x1be1850
08-25 22:16:35.480: I/dalvikvm(24027):   | sysTid=24027 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074255080
08-25 22:16:35.490: I/dalvikvm(24027):   | schedstat=( 49658000 26700000 48 ) utm=1 stm=3 core=1
08-25 22:16:35.490: I/dalvikvm(24027):   at comrootNDK(Native Method)
```

I am clueless as to where i am wrong. If you see above NewStringUTF is adding some garbage value to the c Char* bytes .

1. Any idea about why this is happening
2. Any alternative solution to achieve the above is welcome

I really appreciate if one of you can help me in . Thanks in advance

regds
me

Comment: I was getting the same error due to calling strcat() on an uninitialised char array but issue was resolved once array was initialised.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I resolved this issue by returning byte array instead of String. On the Java side i am now converting the Byte array to Strings .Works fine! Stay away from using NewStringUTF() for Android 4.0 and above as there is already a bug reported on Google Android NDK.

Comment: @rana Please provide code- how you convert byte[] to String on java side. I always get trouble with encoding.

Comment: If you don't want to change your jni code everywhere, you can do new String(byte_array, "utf-8") from jni (get String constructor in jni, and invoke it from jni).

Comment: Jni files are in .so so I cann't edit them to accept byearry instead of strings. so I need to encode the string or do some work around. please any sollution?

Answer (score 22):

The cause of this problem is directly related to a [known UTF-8 bug in the NDK/JNI GetStringUTFChars() function](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2012-June/010403.html) (and probably related functions like NewStringUTF).  These NDK functions do not convert [supplementary Unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane) (i.e., Unicode characters with a value of U+10000 and above) correctly.  This leads to incorrect UTF-8 and subsequent crashes.

I encountered the crash when handling user input text that contained emoticon characters ([see the corresponding Unicode chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F600.pdf)).  Emoticon characters lie in the Supplementary Unicode character range.

**Analysis of the Problem**

1. The Java client passes a string containing a supplementary Unicode
   character to JNI/NDK.
2. JNI uses the NDK function GetStringUTFChars() to extract the contents of the Java string.
3. GetStringUTFChars() returns the string data as incorrect and invalid UTF-8.

[There is a known NDK bug](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2012-June/010403.html) whereby GetStringUTFChars() incorrectly converts supplementary Unicode characters, producing an incorrect and invalid UTF-8 sequence.

In my case, the resulting string was a JSON buffer.  When the buffer was passed to the JSON parser, the parser promptly failed because one of the UTF-8 characters of the extracted UTF-8 had an invalid UTF-8 prefix byte.

**Possible Workaround**

The solution I've used can be summarized as follows:

1. The goal is to prevent GetStringUTFChars() from performing the
   incorrect UTF-8 encoding of the supplementary Unicode character.
2. This is done by the Java client encoding the request string as
   Base64.
3. The Base64-encoded request is passed to JNI.
4. JNI calls GetStringUTFChars(), which extracts the Base64-encoded
   string without performing any UTF-8 encoding.
5. The JNI code then decodes the Base-64 data, producing the original
   UTF-16 (wide char) request string, including the supplementary
   Unicode character.

In this way we circumvent the problem of extracting supplementary Unicode characters from the Java string.  Instead, we convert the data to Base-64 ASCII before calling GetStringUTFChars(), extract the Base-64 ASCII characters using GetStringUTFChars(), and convert the Base-64 data back to wide characters.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! Looking at [Lollipop source code](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/art/runtime/check_jni.cc#549), looks like NewStringUTF() does the check (entry == true), while GetStringUTFChars() does not, so it behaves differently.

Comment: byte[] byteArray =Base64.encodeBase64(messageText.getText().toString().trim().getBytes());
 String encodedString = new String(byteArray);
This way converted the string to Base64 and passed the string to jni but my app still crashing. Any Idea?

Comment: (1) What is the nature of your crash?  Any stack trace with symbols?

(2) Can you post the hex dump of <messageText> before converting it to base-64, and the hex dump of the data returned by GetStringUTFChars() within JNI?

Comment: JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal continuation byte 0xc5
 string: 'Accepted�Ś�7'
in call to NewStringUTF
I was sending v

Comment: for same text app some times crashing and some times not.

Comment: Are you sure you're passing <encodedString> to JNI, or are you still passing the original Unicode string?  If you're passing Base64 characters to JNI you should not be getting a message about an illegal UTF-8 continuation byte.

Comment: it happens with standard java function `File.listFiles(File.java)` so I CAN'T EDIT SOURCE LINUX/JNI/NDK CODE on the phone to solve this problem...

Answer (score 13):

This is how I done this.

1- Char Array to JByteArray.

2- JByteArray to JString.

3- Return jstring to java side.

**JNI Code; (.c) format**

```
jstring Java_com_x_y_z_methodName(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    int size = 16;
    char r[] = {'P', 'K', 'd', 'h', 't', 'X', 'M', 'm', 'r', '1', '8', 'n', '2', 'L', '9', 'K'};
    jbyteArray array = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, size);
    (*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, array, 0, size, r);
    jstring strEncode = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "UTF-8");
    jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String");
    jmethodID ctor = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "<init>", "([BLjava/lang/String;)V");
    jstring object = (jstring) (*env)->NewObject(env, cls, ctor, array, strEncode);

    return object;
}
```

**Java Code;**

```
native String methodName();
```

**Other Approach Not Works For Me;**

I also tried `return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, r)` but returns some characters that are not in the char array, at the end of the string where with the warning of **JNI WARNING: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal  continuation byte 0x40**.

Example; PKdhtXMmr18n2L9K�ؾ�����-DL

**Edit:**

**C++ version**

```
jstring clientStringFromStdString(JNIEnv *env,const std::string &str){
//    return env->NewStringUTF(str.c_str());
    jbyteArray array = env->NewByteArray(str.size());
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(array, 0, str.size(), (const jbyte*)str.c_str());
    jstring strEncode = env->NewStringUTF("UTF-8");
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/lang/String");
    jmethodID ctor = env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "([BLjava/lang/String;)V");
    jstring object = (jstring) env->NewObject(cls, ctor, array, strEncode);
    return object;
}
```

Comment: above solution returning different result for different ABI for example for device that support `arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi` it returning perfect string but device of other type it returning string like `PKdhtXMmr18n2L9K�ؾ�����-DL`

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when I change the file Application.mk

From this line:

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

To:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

Once I changed it back again it fixed the issue.

Comment: Well things might have changed in two and a half years :) But I never got the issue again.

Answer (score 1):

Strings that you pass to NewStringUTF() need to be valid Modified [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).  It looks like the string returned by your start_Inauthroot() function is in some other encoding, or is just returning an invalid string.  You need to convert the string to UTF-8 before passing it to JNI functions.  Or you could use one of the [charset-aware String constructors](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29) to build the String object instead.

Comment: Am sorry to bother you again .. but how to do that .. do you have any suggestions for my following code ,

          jclass strClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/String");

   jmethodID ctorID = env->GetMethodID(strClass, "<init>", "([BLjava/lang/String;)V");     <<<< i might be wrong here 

   jstring encoding = env->NewStringUTF("UTF-8");

  jbyteArray bytes = env->NewByteArray(strlen(rInfo));
  env->SetByteArrayRegion(bytes, 0, strlen(rInfo), (jbyte*)rootInformation);
  grootInfo = (jstring)env->NewObject(strClass, ctrId, bytes,"UTF-8");

Comment: Yes, that looks right, except you need to pass your "encoding" jstring var to NewObject(), not the raw string "UTF-8".  Of course, you need to pass the *actual* encoding of your string, not just "UTF-8".

Comment: But its throwing an error at this line,
       env->GetMethodID(strClass, "<init>", "([BLjava/lang/String;)V"); 

Any idea what should be the reason ?

Comment: _throwing an error at this line,_ `env->GetMethodID(strClass, "<init>", "([BLjava/lang/String;)V");` Note that in 4.0 and higher, answer of `FindClass()` is a local reference.

Comment: Yes, I see that; that's what @rana said.  However, that bit of code works just fine when I run it.  My question is: **what** error is thrown?  `NoSuchMethodError`?  Something else?  `FindClass()` returning a local reference is not a problem, as `strClass` is used immediately in the local scope.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, its not a bug.

NewStringUTF Constructs a new java.lang.String object from an array of characters in **modified UTF-8** encoding.

Modified UTF-8 is not standard UTF-8. See [Modified UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8)

In most cases, UTF-8 encoded string is valid Modified UTF-8. Because Modified UTF-8 and UTF-8 are quite similar. However when it comes to Unicode string beyond Basic Multilingual Plane, they are not compatible.

**Solution:**
pass UTF-8 bytes to Java layer and new String(bytes, "UTF-8") then pass jstring to JNI.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was to place the content on a const char*:

```
const char* string = name_sin.c_str();
jstring utf8 = env_r->NewStringUTF(string);
```

and the function:

```
jclass cls_Env = env_r->FindClass(CLASS_ACTIVITY_NAME); 
jmethodID mid = env_r->GetMethodID(cls_Env, "Delegate",
                                 "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");


//todo importante hacerlo asi, si pasas directamente c_str a veces da error de carater no UTF 8
const char* string = name_sin.c_str();
jstring utf8 = env_r->NewStringUTF(string);

env_r->CallVoidMethod(*object_r, mid, utf8);

env_r->DeleteLocalRef(utf8);
```

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with the same problem from the last day. Finally figured out a solution after a day .. I hope this reply may save someone's day..

The problem was I was calling another function within the native function, used the returned string directly and which caused crash in android older versions

So firstly I saved the string returned from another function to a variable then used it, and the problem gone :D

The below example may clear your concept

```
//older code with error
//here key_ is the string from java code

const char *key = env->GetStringUTFChars(key_, 0);
const char *keyx = getkey(key).c_str();
return env->NewStringUTF(keyx);
```

And here is how I solved this error

```
//newer code which is working
//here key_ is the string from java code

const char *key = env->GetStringUTFChars(key_, 0);
string k = getkey(key);
const char *keyx = k.c_str();
return env->NewStringUTF(keyx);
```

Happy coding :D

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in c++

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT
jstring Java_com_example_ndktest_MainActivity_TalkToJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis, jstring strFromJava)
{
    jboolean isCopy;
    const char* szHTML = env->GetStringUTFChars(strFromJava, &isCopy);

    std::string strMine;
    strMine = szHTML;
    strMine += " --- Hello from the JNI!!";

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(strFromJava, szHTML);
    return env->NewStringUTF(strMine.c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`c` android **ndk** is working as follows

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject thiz,jstring str )
{

    jboolean isCopy;
    const char* szHTML = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, str, &isCopy);
     return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, szHTML);
}
```