# Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) code=-6 on first launch

Tags: java, android, android-4.4-kitkat, sigabrt, nexus-10

I am getting a Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) error when trying to run my app on a Nexus 10 with 4.4.2.

It works on every other device I've tried including my Nexus 7 (2) with 4.4.2

I don't think it's aproblem with the code as I've tried putting breakpoints and logs at the very start of my code (see below) but it doesn't appear to get that far as it will not stop at the breakpoint and the log doesn't appear in the logcat.

```
package com.immediate.imcreader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker;
import com.immediate.imcreader.data.Issue;
import com.immediate.imcreader.data.OrmLiteCarouselMediaDAO;
import com.immediate.imcreader.data.OrmLiteDataCaptureFormDataDAO;
import com.immediate.imcreader.data.OrmLiteIssueDAO;
import com.immediate.imcreader.data.OrmLiteIssueScreenshotsDAO;
import com.immediate.imcreader.data.OrmLitePreferenceDAO;
import com.immediate.imcreader.data.OrmLitePurchasedReceiptDAO;
import com.immediate.imcreader.data.OrmLiteSubscriptionDAO;
import com.immediate.imcreader.purchasing.PurchaseFinishedListener;
import com.immediate.imcreader.purchasing.StoreUtilities;
import com.immediate.imcreader.renderer.RendererActivity;
import com.immediate.imcreader.storefront.AllIssuesFragment;
import com.immediate.imcreader.storefront.DataCapture;
import com.immediate.imcreader.storefront.ErrorFeedbackHandler;
import com.immediate.imcreader.storefront.MoreFromUsFragment;
import com.immediate.imcreader.storefront.NonSwipeableViewPager;
import com.immediate.imcreader.storefront.SimpleWebView;
import com.immediate.imcreader.storefront.SubscribeFragment;
import com.immediate.imcreader.tasks.DownloadJsonTask;
import com.immediate.imcreader.util.FileHelper;
import com.immediate.imcreader.util.JsonCallbackInterface;
import com.immediate.imcreader.util.SupportUtilities;

import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Entry point
 * Just launches the AllIssues activity at the minute
 * @author scottdouglass
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements PurchaseFinishedListener, JsonCallbackInterface {

    public static final String TAG = "IMCReader";

    public static final int SUBSCRIBE_TAB = 0;
    public static final int ISSUES_TAB = 1;
    public static final int MORETITLES_TAB = 2;

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    NonSwipeableViewPager mViewPager;

    private StoreUtilities storeUtilities;
    private Boolean buildAppStoreFront = false;
    private Boolean getProductDetails = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.v(TAG, "onCreate started");
        initSplashScreen();
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        if (getActionBar() != null) {
            getActionBar().hide();
        }
```

The libraries I have installed are:

- android-support-v13.jar
- in-app-purchasing-1.0.3.jar
- libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar
- ormlite-android-4.47.jar
- omrlite-core-4.45.jar
- picasso-2.1.1.jar
- urbanairship-lib-3.3.0.jar

This is what I'm getting back in my logcat:

```
05-08 12:57:35.956  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader W/dalvikvm﹕ JNI WARNING: NewStringUTF input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xff
05-08 12:57:35.956  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader W/dalvikvm﹕ string: 'en_Latn_US_�_GB'
05-08 12:57:35.956  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader W/dalvikvm﹕ in Llibcore/icu/ICU;.addLikelySubtags:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; (NewStringUTF)
05-08 12:57:35.961  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
05-08 12:57:35.961  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41567ca8 self=0x414a1408
05-08 12:57:35.961  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ | sysTid=13079 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074114900
05-08 12:57:35.961  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ | state=R schedstat=( 15667415 6358417 55 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=1
05-08 12:57:35.981  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #00  pc 000012f6  /system/lib/libcorkscrew.so (unwind_backtrace_thread+29)
05-08 12:57:35.986  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #01  pc 00060576  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpNativeStack(DebugOutputTarget const*, int)+33)
05-08 12:57:35.986  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #02  pc 00054578  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThreadEx(DebugOutputTarget const*, Thread*, bool)+395)
05-08 12:57:35.986  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #03  pc 000545e6  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThread(Thread*, bool)+25)
05-08 12:57:35.986  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #04  pc 00038770  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-08 12:57:35.986  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #05  pc 00039ba8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-08 12:57:35.986  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #06  pc 0003bf7a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-08 12:57:35.986  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #07  pc 000143da  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
05-08 12:57:35.986  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #08  pc 00014bbe  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
05-08 12:57:35.986  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #09  pc 0001db4c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
05-08 12:57:35.986  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #10  pc 0004e082  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+397)
05-08 12:57:35.986  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #11  pc 00026f60  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #12  pc 0002df78  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #13  pc 0002b5dc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #14  pc 00060788  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+391)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #15  pc 000686f6  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #16  pc 00026f60  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #17  pc 0002df78  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #18  pc 0002b5dc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #19  pc 000604a4  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+335)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #20  pc 00049c6a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #21  pc 0004cd34  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #22  pc 0004da5a  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+353)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #23  pc 0000105a  /system/bin/app_process
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ #24  pc 0000e3e4  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+47)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at libcore.icu.ICU.addLikelySubtags(Native Method)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.text.TextUtils.getLayoutDirectionFromLocale(TextUtils.java:1740)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.content.res.Configuration.setLayoutDirection(Configuration.java:1295)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.content.res.Configuration.updateFrom(Configuration.java:820)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.content.res.Resources.updateConfiguration(Resources.java:1557)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.content.res.Resources.updateConfiguration(Resources.java:1511)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.content.res.Resources.<init>(Resources.java:202)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ResourcesManager.getTopLevelResources(ResourcesManager.java:199)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:1534)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:488)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ContextImpl.init(ContextImpl.java:2025)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ContextImpl.init(ContextImpl.java:2004)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4166)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-08 12:57:35.991  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 12:57:35.996  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-08 12:57:35.996  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-08 12:57:35.996  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-08 12:57:35.996  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-08 12:57:35.996  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader I/dalvikvm﹕ [ 05-08 12:57:35.996 13079:13079 E/dalvikvm ]
    VM aborting
05-08 12:57:35.996  13079-13079/com.immediate.imcreader A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00003317 (code=-6), thread 13079 (diate.imcreader)
```

Comment: I am getting same problem on my Galaxy S5. Did you solve this? I only have one test device so hard to tell if on S5. Also crash is once is a while. Not constant. Usually after resuming from onPause

Comment: @KatedralPillon - Afraid not, ended up leaving this project and the problem was never resolved... A mystery I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

... a little late to the party but I ran into a similar situation when adding KitKat support to one of our older 3.x apps.

Apparently there is an Android bug related to UTF encoding.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127817/android-ics-4-0-ndk-newstringutf-is-crashing-down-the-app) led us in the right direction and [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64892) is the issue.

Comment: The app is compiled for Android 4.x, I have checked all XML and JSON I use in the app and it only fails on the Nexus 10. I have upgraded the Nexus 10 from 4.2 to 4.3 and finally 4.4. It failed on all versions...

Answer (score 1):

That happens to me in this case:

- I load a View onCreate and after, a Function is called very fast and access to that view.

The View can be null in some instant!!!

search all views that you load in OnCreate and write this:

```
if(view!=null){
   //DO Whatever
}else{
   Log.e(TAG,"ANDROID BUG");
}
```

**EDIT: I have realized that it wasn't because the function called very fast. It was because I have a Listener and I didn't unregister when OnDestroy(). And When OnCreate, I had two listener. One with NULL result and the other one OK.**

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {                       
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mSensorManager!=null){mSensorManager.unregisterListener(listener);}
}
```

I hope this helps to someone :)