# Why do emojis make my app crash

Tags: android, android-studio, emoji

I created a business card for a udacity exercise, but when checking the final product on my phone it kept crashing without opening.
The code was fine, I checked it thousands of time, and was without errors.
I thought it may have been because the image I used was too big, so I resized it, but nothing, it kept on crashing.
Then I decided to try to delete the emojis I used in the TextView, and it worked again,but in Android Studio it didn't give me any errors, so why it didn't work on the phone?

Comment: What does `adb logcat` have to say?

Comment: 25086-25086/? A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xf0
02-19 19:37:33.097 25138-25179/? W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
02-19 19:37:31.564 25086-25086/? A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     string: 'location:Bristol

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127817/android-ics-4-0-ndk-newstringutf-is-crashing-down-the-app