# JNI: Catch NewStringUTF Inner-Exception

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, jnienv

My JNI code receives a `char* src` from an external source, converts it to `String` using `jstring jStr = env->NewStringUTF(src)`, and passes the result `jStr` to the upper - Java layer.

Some input `src` values cause the following runtime error (within the call to `NewStringUTF`):

```
A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xf8
A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]     string: 'radio abcdefg ���� ����� ��� ����'
A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]     input: '0x72 0x61 0x64 0x69 0x6f 0x20 0x62 0x72 0x65 0x73 0x6c 0x65 0x76 0x20 <0xf8> 0xe3 0xe9 0xe5 0x20 0xe1 0xf8 0xf1 0xec 0xe1 0x20 0xf7 0xe5 0xec 0x20 0xe4 0xf0 0xe7 0xec'
A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]     in call to NewStringUTF
```

None of the methods I used could "catch" this **NewStringUTF** error/exception:

- Placing `if (env->ExceptionCheck() == JNI_TRUE)` after the `NewStringUTF` call.
- Placing `if (env->ExceptionOccurred())` after the `NewStringUTF` call.
- bounding the call to `NewStringUTF` by a `try...catch` block.

**Note:** The question is focused on **catching the exception** (and by that controlling its impact, so it doesn't crash the application), and not necessarily on resolving it (although it could be useful).

I'm using Android Studio v2.3.3 with NDK v15.2 (most recent to date).

**Your assistance would be much obliged.**

Comment: The exception is telling you that your assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: Maybe haven't been emphasized enough, but the question is focused on **catching the exception** (and by that controlling its impact, so it doesn't crash the application), and not necessarily on resolving it. Possibly, the crash occurs due to lower-level code executed within `NewStringUTF`?

Comment: Docs say `NewStringUTF` returns NULL if there's an error building the string. So maybe that's all there is to it: check for NULL and ignore the debug output that nobody except you will ever see

Comment: Thanks for the kind will and suggestion. The thing is: It behaves differently than stated on the formal Docs. It crashes the application (so that checking for `NULL` isn't useful).

Comment: This has a few workarounds for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127817/android-ics-4-0-ndk-newstringutf-is-crashing-down-the-app even down to using a char array.

Comment: @WLGfx, thanks for that (+1). I'm aware of this question and the solutions suggested in its context. I wanted to merely *catch* the exception, but as, apparently, this is not possible, I'll have to use a workaround. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

> Text datetypes are for text.

Is the data being passed via `char *` text?

> There is no text but encoded text.

What is the character encoding of the text?

> NewStringUTF: Constructs a new java.lang.String object from an array of characters in modified UTF-8 encoding.

Android text tends to be standard UTF-8. This looks like Windows-1255 (Hebrew) but only the writer can say.

Regardless, the solution is to use Java character encoding functions to convert your encoded text from a byte array to a Java string (UTF-16). It is easier to call such methods in Java rather than via JNI. So, if it fits your dataflow, copy the `char *` to a jbyteArray and pass that back to Java where it can be easily converted to a text datatype using the relevant encoding.