# env->NewStringUTF(s) get crash and different ABI version returning different string value

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, abi, ndk-build

Want to generate random string of fix length from JNI function for that i have used below function

```
static const char alphanum[] =
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

jstring Utils::getRandomString(JNIEnv *env, const int len) {


    char s[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        int p = rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1);
        s[i] = alphanum[p];
    }
    s[len] = 0;

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "LOG_TAG", "getRandomString  %s", s);


  jstring  temp= env->NewStringUTF(s);

    return temp;
}
```

but application get crash for line `jstring  temp= env->NewStringUTF(s);` only for ABI version `armeabi-v7a`

for the solution i have tried  [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34218851/2941375)

```
jstring Utils::getRandomString(JNIEnv *env, const int len) {


    char s[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        int p = rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1);
        s[i] = alphanum[p];
    }
    s[len] = 0;
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "LOG_TAG", "getRandomString 2 %s", s);


    jbyteArray array = env->NewByteArray(len);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(array, 0, len, (const jbyte *) s);
    jstring strEncode = env->NewStringUTF("UTF-8");
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/lang/String");
    jmethodID ctor = env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "([BLjava/lang/String;)V");
    jstring object = (jstring) env->NewObject(cls, ctor, array, strEncode);


    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "LOG_TAG", "getRandomString 3 %s",
                        env->GetStringUTFChars(object, 0));
//    jstring  temp= env->NewStringUTF(s);

    return object;
}
```

but it working fine for ABI version `armeabi-v7a` when we execute same code on ABI `x86` it returning unexpected output like **PKdhtXMmr18n2L9K�ؾ�����-DL**

please provide some solution that return generated string. `env->NewStringUTF()` working for ABI version `x86` it get crash on `armeabi-v7a`.

thanks in advance

Comment: if you have `char s[len];` then you cannot use `s[len] = 0;` - you can use only [0..len-1] indexes

Comment: @pskink you saved my day,let me test on more device thanks

Comment: i have tested if i removed s[len] = 0 then it returning string like this vaxturfxligzdhkwdyfmymjentckupgh�i�������L���� how to end the string

Comment: you cannot simply remove setting `0` at the end of your string - it is a string termination special character - more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string

Comment: i have updated the   `char s[len];`  to `char s[len+1];` it resolve the issue,thanks

Comment: good, this is how it should be done

Comment: @pskink thank you,also there is no requirement for  add this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/34218851/2941375 removed this,issue is only with array length